# image url to file() object using js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

For a registration module in my vue app I let users upload images in a form. I upload these images to my storage and save the download url of this photo in the registration. When editing a registration I need to get the photo's out of the storage which is simple since I got the url. But I need it to be a file() object. I have found ways to turn it into a blob but it needs to be a file. How can I do this?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? i'm facing a similar problem in react

Answer (score 34):

It can be done by requesting a blob and generating a File object. It is necessary to specify the MIME type of the blob.

```
const urlToObject= async()=> {
  const response = await fetch(image);
  // here image is url/location of image
  const blob = await response.blob();
  const file = new File([blob], 'image.jpg', {type: blob.type});
  console.log(file);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can get blocked by CORS policy when fetching the image.

Comment: Draw an Image element then convert to file
https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/handle-images-cors-error-in-chrome
 then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 3):

The ES6 way, **with Promise**:

```
const blobUrlToFile = (blobUrl:string): Promise<File> => new Promise((resolve) => {
    fetch(blobUrl).then((res) => {
      res.blob().then((blob) => {
        // please change the file.extension with something more meaningful
        // or create a utility function to parse from URL
        const file = new File([blob], 'file.extension', {type: blob.type})
        resolve(file)
      })
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are letting the user upload a file, you already have the file as a `File` object.

But if you wanna convert it to a blob for making some edits and convert it back to a `File` object, you can use the `File()` constructor for converting a blob to a File.

`const file = new File([blob], "imagename.png");`

Also, notice that the File() constructor takes an array of blobs as argument and not a single blob.

Comment: I do not since the upload is in an other module. I am getting the data from the database and thus any local items including the file is gone. 

I don't need it to ever be a blob. I guess It could be a workaround to change the url into an blob and then the blob into an file but I imagine there be a more straight forward way.